# trying to install LMMS from software center and i have this error

Tags: lmms

This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
lmms: Depends: lmms-common (= 2:1.1.3-1kxstudio5.2) but 2:1.1.3-1kxstudio5.2 is to be installed
      Depends: libqt4-xml (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
      Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
      Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
      Depends: stk-rawwaves but it is not going to be installed
i need help
```

Comment: Have you contacted the maintainer of whatever third party repository you are using?

Comment: How do I do that

Comment: I wrongly asumed you were using a PPA, nevermind.

Comment: help me how do i go about solving this problem

Answer (score 2):

Remove any previous installed repository :

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:dobey/audiotools
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:kxstudio-debian/apps
```

then remove any `lmms` installed if you have :

```
sudo apt-get remove lmms
```

this remove any previous installed files of `lmms`. Then you can install from your software center with no problem.